# How to install roboearth on ubuntu 12.04 ros fuerte 64 bit

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ros-fuerte, roboearth, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
Who can tell me how to install How to install roboearth on ubuntu 12.04 ros fuerte  64 bit.
Following website:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth
I can not finish the installation.

Step 1.

```
rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/fuerte 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'
```

No problem.

Step 2:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ias-common ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-addons ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo ros-fuerte-vision-opencv ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping ros-fuerte-client-rosjava-jni.
```

but there is not a package named ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-addons.
So I cannot finish

step 3:

```
rosmake roboearth
```

Then I try to download and install from svn.
There are two errors.

One is it need pcl_visualization

While I compile  pcl_visualization
it said it need eigen.

I think there is an easy way for us to install and use roboearth.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36836/how-to-install-roboearth-on-ubuntu-12.04-ros-fuerte--64-bit/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We recently upgraded it to be compatible to ROS Fuerte, so you might try it again.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) on 2012-07-23**:
I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with ROS Fuerte and I tried these same steps right now and I am having the same problem.  Could it be that the rosinstall file is pulling from a branch, so that I am not getting the recent upgrade?  Or is it possible that the fuerte updates aren't making it to 11.10?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is the same, we still can not find ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-addons. Please give a detail explanation on it.

---

Originally posted by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) with karma: 287 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-02-26**:
I have the same problem :(

@ddimarco
can you give us more details ?

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2013-02-27**:
Are you sure you are using the instructions for ROS Fuerte from http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth_stack#Installation ?

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-02-27**:
yes,I'm sure
I have used re_object_recorder and re_object_detector_gui which are packages of RoboEarth Stack
and I'm sure that I have use the whole instructions from
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth_stack#Installation

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2013-02-27**:
I cannot reproduce that problem, the stack does not depend on ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-addons. Please open a new issue and describe your problem in detail.